# Como alterar a subnet do Docker?

Tags: docker

Estou em uma rede que utiliza a faixa de IP `172.17.42.1`, infelizmente a mesma do Docker. Por conta disso não consigo mais acessar minha rede local pois as duas redes entram em conflito. É possível alterar o endereço de IP do Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um problema comum e a solução é simples. Primeiro pare o serviço do Docker:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

Para ver informações sobre o roteamento nat, execute o comando:

```
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
```

Desligue e remova a conexão `docker0`:

```
ip link set dev docker0 down
ip addr del 172.17.42.1/16 dev docker0
```

Agora adicione uma nova conexão para `docker0` e levante essa conexão:

```
ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev docker0
ip link set dev docker0 up
```

Rode o comando abaixo para visualizar informações sobre a conexão `docker0`:

```
ip addr show docker0
```

Inicialize o serviço do Docker:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Provavelmente agora você conseguira se conectar a sua rede local.

Para visualizar mais informações sobre sua rede, execute o comando abaixo:

```
iptables -t nat -L -n
```

Comment: Quando usamos o Docker no MAC OSX ou Windows pode ocorrer um problema de conflito de rede parecido com este, porém no Virtual Box. Neste caso podemos usar o comando `VBoxManage` como no exemplo:

`VBoxManage modifyvm "Win7-64bits" --natnet1 "192.168.199.0/24"` 

A solução completa pode ser vista em [http://joao-parana.com.br/blog/interface-bridge-no-boot2docker/](http://joao-parana.com.br/blog/interface-bridge-no-boot2docker/)